# How to edit the position of value labels in plot.likert?

Tags: r, plot, likert

I have a dataframe of scores 
`scores <- data.frame(var1=c(1,3,5,6,1,4,10,2,5,3,7), var2=c(10,9,1,4,3,3,4,7,8,10,10))`

which I transform into a factor with three levels as:

```
library(likert)
library(dplyr)

scores_factor <- scores %>% sapply(., cut, c(0, 6, 8, 10), include.lowest = TRUE, labels = c("Negative", "Okay", "Positive")) %>% data.frame
```

and then transforming it into a likert item and plotting it using the likert.plot from the "likert" package:

```
likert_scores <- likert(scores_factor)
p <- plot(likert_scores, 
          low.color="#ED5949", 
          neutral.color="#F3CA71", 
          high.color="#7CB166") +
     labs(title= "Hello world!") +
     theme(plot.title=element_text(size=16, 
           face="bold", color="black"), 
           plot.subtitle=element_text(size=11, 
           face="italic", color="black"), 
           text = element_text(color = "#333333", 
           axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
           legend.position="right") +
     theme_hc()
plot(p)
```

Now, the problem is that the likert.plot displays the edge value labels **not inside** the bars. I wish to find a way to print the labels inside the bars without having to resort on building a stacked barplot from scratch with ggplot2? Is this possible? If not what could be an alternative?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: What packages are you using?

Comment: Apologies, I'll edit the post with the packages included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day of trying to solve this myself, found a work-around which I post below in case others want to benefit from it.

For the history, a likert item stores the proportions of the factor's levels in the position:

```
likert_scores[["results"]][["Negative"]][1] 
likert_scores[["results"]][["Okay"]][1]
likert_scores[["results"]][["Positive"]][1]
```

(for column 1 in case you have three-leveled factors like in the current post)

Therefore, we add the following lines of code to print the percentage labels for both columns var1 and var2 through `geom_text`:

```
geom_text(label=paste0(c(round(likert_scores[["results"]][["Negative"]][1]), round(likert_scores[["results"]][["Okay"]][1]), 
                         round(likert_scores[["results"]],[["Positive"]][1]),round(likert_scores[["results"]][["Negative"]][2]), round(likert_scores[["results"]][["Okay"]][2]), 
                         round(likert_scores[["results"]][["Positive"]][2])), "%"), position = position_stack(vjust= .5))
```

but we also need to change the parameters to not allow `likert.plot()` to print the original labels in order to not overlap with the new labels. Altogether, this is my current solution:

```
p <- plot(likert_scores, 
          low.color="#ED5949", 
          neutral.color="#F3CA71", 
          high.color="#7CB166", 
          centered= FALSE, 
          plot.percents=FALSE, 
          plot.percent.low=FALSE, 
          plot.percent.high=FALSE, 
          plot.percent.neutral = FALSE) +
     geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust= .5),
               label=paste0(
                            c(round(likert_scores[["results"]][["Negative"]][1]), 
                              round(likert_scores[["results"]][["Okay"]][1]), 
                              round(likert_scores[["results"]][["Positive"]][1]),
                              round(likert_scores[["results"]][["Negative"]][2]), 
                              round(likert_scores[["results"]][["Okay"]][2]),
                              round(likert_scores[["results"]][["Positive"]][2])), 
                            "%"))
```

And the new labels are in place!

[image]